# Detect application is in display mode (double click home button)

Tags: ios, iphone

I don't know what to call this state. so apology for the title mistake.

Is there a way for me to check user is about leaving my app. for example, when user tap 2x on home screen, and recent open apps is showing. I want to know in this state, so i can modify something on my app.

I check all delegates method don't cover this. `applicationWillResignActive:` & `applicationDidEnterBackground:` didn't get fired.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: In this case the `applicationWillResignActive:` app delegate method should be called. I just tested my own app and it is. If the user picks another app then the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` delegate will be called. This assumes your app was being used when the user double-tapped the Home button.

Comment: wow, thank you for pointing that out. didn't know what to call, hence don't know the search keyword. thanks a million.

Comment: @rmaddy User hasn't pick another app yet. user just open the multitasking switcher. How to know if in this state? didn't call `applicationDidEnterBackground` coz the app hasn't in the background yet.

Comment: There is no way to know why your app resigned active. There are many possible reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect this. From the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) ("App Termination" heading):

> **Important:** The applicationWillTerminate: method is not called if your
>   app is currently suspended.
>
> Even if you develop your app using iOS SDK 4 and later, you must still
>   be prepared for your app to be killed without any notification. The
>   user can kill apps explicitly using the multitasking UI. In addition,
>   if memory becomes constrained, the system might remove apps from
>   memory to make more room. Suspended apps are not notified of
>   termination but if your app is currently running in the background
>   state (and not suspended), the system calls the
>   applicationWillTerminate: method of your app delegate. Your app cannot
>   request additional background execution time from this method.

Comment: actually, there's many app done this. I'm sure it can. I know some : paypal and ynab apps. they hide their view when user taps double home page. this only effect iOS7 though, coz you can see others screen.